# How do you update GTK+ and/or Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, updates, gtk, gtk3

I found a theme that I wish to run, and it says that is is meant to run on Gnome 3.12. It says:

> **Important note:** This theme is designed for Gnome 3.12. May or may not work with other versions of Gnome-shell and GTK.

First of all, the difference between Gnome and GTK is fairly blurry to me still. From what I understand, GTK is the toolkit for which Gnome is built with. I also am not even sure that Ubuntu uses Gnome in any form. Doesn't Ubuntu use Unity instead of Gnome? Or does it use Unity AND some Gnome stuff? I do see some miscellaneous packages in Synaptic that look like Gnome-*.

Anyway, I want to use [this theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Zukitwo?content=140562) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My OS is up-to-date, and I have recently ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` which I believe upgrades all packages to their most recent version.

However, the `libgtk-3-0`, `libgtk-3-common` and `libgtk-3-bin` packages says that I am running 3.10.8. Shouldn't the `libgtk` stuff be 3.12 since I ran the `sudo apt-get upgrade` command?

How do I update GTK and/or GNOME so that I can use this theme?

**Theme: [Zukitwo](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Zukitwo?content=140562)** on Gnome-Look.org

Please note I am using a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install (not Ubuntu GNOME). I have not installed any desktop environments, which means I am using Unity. Everything is up-to-date according to Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: After Gnome 3.10 ,  there happened huge differences on Gnome side,  it's not  compatible with current Ubuntu. Even compiz won't work properly. Ubuntu team patches Gnome to use it.  You had better wait until Ubuntu team patches and upgrades gtk3.10 and gnome stuff.

Comment: Great info. Thank you for the suggestion. I ended up going to Linux Mint Cinnamon, and I am much happier. This theme also happens to be available for Cinnamon, however I don't use it. I suppose this question was more about how to install or upgrade Gnome/GTK 3.12 in Ubuntu. I still don't know what the difference between them is, but it doesn't really matter. As you mentioned, Gnome has grown incompatible... Thanks for touching base on this old topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gnome Team have a ppa which has Gnome 3.12 in it.
Please note last time I looked, a few months ago it was not ready for general use.

To install Gnome <strike>alongside</strike> Unity you need to run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-deskop
```

You will need to select and use the GDM desktop manager when asked to choose.

EDIT: At least as of 2014-08-26, there is a version conflict in dependencies for gnome-control-center and ubuntu-control-center (for versions of gnome-settings-daemon).  They will not live side by side happily unless you install an older version of gnome.

Comment: Thanks for response. Sorry I didn't mark your answer earlier... I left Ubuntu for LM :)

Comment: This effectively changed Ubuntu interface to something horrible. And uninstall just crashed my system. The good thing is I moved to Ubuntu 16 through a clean reinstall...